# Matlab Zero Tolerance in rank function

Tags: matlab

I am wondering if there is technical or theoretical reason on why Matlab on [rank](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/rank.html) function considers as zero the value `max(size(A))*eps(norm(A))`. Can you please provide some intuition?

Thank you!

Comment: please give sample value for `a`, I am suspicious to `a` and `norm(a)` .

Answer (score 0):

The following answer is not based on proper mathematical reasoning, it is just some speculations (as you were asking for intuition):

`norm(A)` is the order of magnitude of the matrix entries.

`eps(norm(A))` is thus the accuracy that the floating point representation of the matrix entries typically has.

Now, consider you add `N` numbers that should theoretically add up to zero, but each of them has an error of `eps` to it ... I think we would expect an error in the order of `sqrt(N) * eps` for the result.

Then, given that the algorithm that computes the rank performs `N^2` operations on the matrix entries (where `N` is its size) to result in a number that is checked against zero, the error that we would then expect is what you stated in your question.

What I don't know, is the algorithm that Matlab uses really of complexity `N^2`?

Comment: Thanks for answering, following the reasoning you presented, why we expect an error of order of `sqrt(N)*eps` and not `N^2*eps`?

Comment: In general, statistical errors add up quadratically, see [here](http://lectureonline.cl.msu.edu/~mmp/labs/error/e2.htm). For example, if we wanted to add two numbers with an error of `eps` each, the error on the sum would be `sqrt(eps^2 + eps^2) = sqrt(2) * eps`.